# I think I'm misusing php mkdir

Tags: php, apache, mkdir

I am writing a web application in PHP and I want to give it a feature where a user names their instance of the application, and then PHP makes a folder (directory) structure for the app based on that name.

To do this I wrote a PHP script that takes a $_POST variable from an HTML form and then uses the mkdir() function.  This isn't the actual script, but here is the idea:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="foldername">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $foldername = 'test';
    mkdir($foldername, 0777, false);
?>
```

I assigned the name 'test' to the variable $foldername because I thought maybe I was using incorrect syntax when I originally assigned it the value of $_POST['foldername'].

So here's the TL;DR question:
This script does NOT work when I press submit on the web form.  It doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't make the file either.  However, when I run it from the command line, it DOES make the folder.  I don't think it's a permissions problem since I am the owner of the directory and its parent.  I am running this on Apache on my own machine.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or any ideas on an alternative method?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.5.9.. I'm pretty sure it's the stable relase

Comment: When you say "it doesn't produce an error" did you actually check your error logs?

Comment: you never check if the form was submitted, so you execute the mkdir EVERY TIME the page loads. you need `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== 'POST') { mkdir stuff ... }` to prevent that. and then. and you don't get an error,b ecause mkdir doesn't output errors. it just returns boolean false on failure, which you're not checking for.

Comment: `I am the owner of the directory and its parent.` are you also the apache user?

Comment: @chris85 I think so? I'm not real sure, this is my first time using Apache. when I test the HTML page, I just use it like a regular user.

Comment: @MarcB I think you may be wrong, [MKDIR emits warning error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#refsect1-function.mkdir-errors) in the case you suggest.

Comment: apache runs as its own user. if YOUR account is the owner of the dir/parent, then apache almost certainly WON'T have the rights to make any changes in there.

Comment: @KennyLajara: yes, but 99.99999% of problems here tend to be from users who've supressed/disabled warnings, so it's basically easier to just assume that no warnings will ever be output.

Comment: Try sudo chmod 777 -R on the location to check if it is a permission issue else use (x)debug or error_log to see what error is given. Do change the permissions back once you verified this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by using an absolute path?

```
<?php
    $foldername = '/root/dir/test'; // Note the slash at the beggining
    // $foldername = 'test';
    mkdir($foldername, 0777, false);
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Kenny Lajara, adding the slashes seems to be the part I was missing

Comment: Glad it help could help you.